# Input Formatting in Flutter's Drop Down Menu text field

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I want to use DropDownMenu's text field with Input Formatter but I couldn't find any option. Is there a way to capitalise first alphabets of all words in DropDownMenu's field while user is entering info using keyboard (web or mobile)?

Where DropDownMenu is not required, I have used inputFormatters property of TextFormField. But for this case filterable/searchable DropDownMenu is required.

Other methods using Stack to build my own searchable DropDownMenu does not work when I want to select a menu item by tapping.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DropdownMenu widget now supports inputFormatters property like TextFormField in flutter channle beta. It should be flowing down to stable channel soon.

**Example:**

```
DropdownMenu(
  dropdownMenuEntries: /*....*/ ,
  inputFormatters: []
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as i had done in my previous project.

```
class Capitalization extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.text.isEmpty) {
      return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
    } else {
      return TextEditingValue(
        text: newValue.text.replaceFirst(newValue.text[0], newValue.text[0].toUpperCase()),
        selection: newValue.selection,
        composing: newValue.composing,
      );
    }
  }
}

TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [Capitalization()],
  onChanged: (value) {
  },
),
```

Comment: I have used such class extending TextInputFormatter but DropDownMenu does not have a property to add a input formatter. My question is for that.

Comment: No, the DropdownButton and DropdownMenuItem widgets in Flutter do not have a built-in property to add an input formatter like the TextInputFormatter used with TextField or TextFormField.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is my question, any other way to achieve that?

Comment: What I want to do? - tappable, searchable, filterable dropdown with text field where in I can add new values if already not present in dropdown, with capital first alphabet. (I already have input formatter function)

Comment: I also have function to fetch data from Firestone for my dropdown and function to add data into firestorm if its a new value.